# MP4 Atom Parsing - where to configure time...?

Tags: audio, mp4, multimedia

I've written an MP4 parser that can read atoms in an MP4 just fine, and stitch them back together - the result is a technically valid MP4 file that Quicktime can open and such, but it can't play any audio as I believe the timing/sampling information is all off. I should probably mention I'm only interested in audio.

What I'm doing is trying to take the moov atoms/etc from an existing MP4, and then take only a subset of the mdat atom in the file to create a new, smaller MP4. In doing so I've altered the `duration` in the `mvhd` atom, as well as the duration in the `mdia` header. There are no `tkhd` atoms in this file that have edits, so I believe I don't need to alter the durations there - what am I missing?

In creating the new MP4 I'm properly sectioning the `mdat` block with a wide box, and keeping the 'mdat' header/size in their right places - I make sure to update the size with the new content.

Now it's entirely 110% possible I'm missing something crucial about the format, but if this is possible I'd love to get the final piece. Anybody got any input/ideas?

Code can be found at the following link:

https://gist.github.com/ryanmcgrath/958c602cff133bd7fa0b

Comment: What kind of audio do these files store? Raw PCM, compressed CBR or compressed VBR?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark here and say that you're not updating your `stbl` offsets properly. At least I didn't (at first glance) see your python doing that anywhere.

## STSC

Lets start with the location of data. Packets are written into the file in terms of chunks, and the header tells the decoder where each "block" of these chunks exists.  The `stsc` table says how many items per chunk exist. The `first chunk` says where that new chunk starts. It's a little confusing, but look at my example. This is saying that you have 100 samples per chunkk, up to the 8th chunk. At the 8th chunk there are 98 samples.

[image]

## STCO

That said, you also have to track where the offsets of these chunks are. That's the job of the `stco` table.  So, where in the file is chunk offset 1, or chunk offset 2, etc.

[image]

If you modify any data in `mdat` you have to maintain these tables. You can't just chop `mdat` data out, and expect the decoder to know what to do.

As if this wasn't enough, now you have to also maintain the sample time table (`stts`) the sample size table (`stsz`) and if this was video, the sync sample table (`stss`).

## STTS

`stts` says how long a sample should play for in units of the timescale. If you're doing audio the timescale is probably 44100 or 48000 (kHz).

[image]

If you've lopped off some data, now everything could potentially be out of sync. If all the values here have the exact same duration though you'd be OK.

## STSZ

`stsz` says what size each sample is in bytes. This is important for the decoder to be able to start at a chunk, and then go through each sample by its size.

[image]

Again, if all the sample sizes are exactly the same you'd be OK. Audio tends to be pretty much the same, but video stuff varies a lot (with keyframes and whatnot)

## STSS

And last but not least we have the `stss` table which says which frame's are keyframes. I only have experience with AAC, but every audio frame is considered a keyframe.  In that case you can have one entry that describes all the packets.

[image]

---

In relation to your original question, the time display isn't always honored the same way in each player. The most accurate way is to sum up the durations of all the frames in the header and use that as the total time. Other players use the metadata in the track headers.  I've found it best to just keep all the values the same and then players are happy.

If you're doing all that and I missed it in the script then can you post a sample mp4 and a standalone app and I can try to help you out.

Comment: Hey - not ignoring your answer, just busy at the moment. I'll probably come back to it in the next day or two!

Comment: @RyanMcGrath no sweat, take your time

Comment: This was incredibly informative and helpful, even though I went about the problem a different way in the end (avoiding the need for this entirely, albeit annoyingly so...). You did wind up being right as far as I could tell though.

Comment: Awesome post @devshorts I am wondering if there is any limit to the number of samples per chunk. Can I have one chunk with all my raw aac samples? Or do I need to split the samples up into different chunks?

Comment: @Soham you can have them all be the same. Per the spec "Each table entry corresponds to a set of consecutive chunks, each of which contains the same number of samples. Furthermore, each of the samples in these chunks must use the same sample description. Whenever the number of samples per chunk or the sample description changes, you must create a new table entry. If all the chunks have the same number of samples per chunk and use the same sample description, this table has one entry."

Comment: @devshorts all the m4as (audio, with constant bit rate) that i open up have variable sizes in STSZ ... each sample has a different size. How is that possible? How do we calculate the size of a compressed sample? (I would think that compressed audio samples should have the same sample size)

Comment: @Soham, that's up to the driver.  Constant bit rate does not mean constant data size.  Constant bit rate is usually a suggestion, and there are variances around that.  If you have AAC the packet size may vary slightly. PCM is always the same size since its always raw, but with psychoacoustic removal you can get variances in compression.

Comment: What's the name of this software that parses and prints MP4 data like that?

Comment: @Tomer if you want a programmatic parser I wrote one as an example of using my f# parser combinator library: https://github.com/devshorts/ParsecClone/tree/master/Samples/Mp4Matcher

Comment: @devshorts Thank you, very useful

Comment: @devshorts How can I extract above information if I have only mdat atom?

Comment: If you only have mdat you basically just have binary data with no metadata so you can't. It's basically garbage without the metadata

Comment: Can you tell which tool did you use to parse the file?

Comment: I think it was called QuickTime atom viewer