# How the player parses the MP4 file and plays the tracks in it?

Tags: video, mp4, codec, mp4parser

I am trying to understand from where the MP4 parsing begins in Player. I mean that I needs the dataflow from where the parsing begins and how the mvhd, tkhd, mdat and metadata are utilised

Thank You

Comment: Do you mean the file format? It’s documented in iso 14496-12

Answer (score 0):

See also: [**`MP4 Atom Parsing - where to configure time…?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552833/2057709)

The parsing happens within `moov` (mvhd,tkhd, etc).

There is no data flow, you parse the neccessary`moov` data to extract a frame (audio or video), once extracted they are passed to the relevant a/v decoder (*eg:* H264/H265/aac/mp3) to decode a picture or sound.

For a keyframe you look at `STSS` (SS = sync sample) to find a keyframe's bytes location within `mdat`section. Then use `STSZ` atom to know how much size of bytes for this keyframe. Send those bytes to an H264 decoder to see a frame/image. If you need other info like *timecode of this frame* then you check `STTS` (Time-To-Sample) atom for the numbers.