# What's the most performant way to encode an mp4 video of frames from a webgl canvas using Javascript in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, html5-canvas, mp4

I can capture the frames from the canvas using readPixels (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels) but then what?

I think there are a few wasm versions of ffmpeg but they're slow.

I found this web assembly mp4 encoder but it's no longer supported and doesn't work in Chrome on my phone (Android 13).

Any other suggestions?

Comment: _"...Doesn't work in Chrome on my phone"_ what mobile OS are you testing on?

Answer (score 2):

> *"What's the most performant way to encode an mp4 video of frames from a webgl canvas using Javascript in a web browser?"*

The most performant way would be to use the **WebCodecs API**. It is a built-in feature of Chrome browser (and is a supported feature on Android).

An MP4 is a container of frames for audio and video. You want to first encode your pixels in a compressed video format (eg: H.264) then either play that H.264 file with a desktop media player (eg: VLC), or if you need to display it in the browser then it will have to be muxed into an MP4 container...

If creating your own muxer then you need to look up the [**MP4** specifications](https://ossrs.net/lts/zh-cn/assets/files/ISO_IEC_14496-14-MP4-2020-379935634d95ce9ab9c0eca6d47c6b79.pdf).
 (note that [**MOV**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicktime-file-format) specs are also usable since both formats are from the same ISO-14496 specs).

MP4 data is mostly integers (not including the audio / video data) so you can just create a (normal) array, fill it with valid values for an MP4's data, then add (paste bytes of) your encoded frames within the MP4 data, to finally save as a playable MP4 file.

Example of writing an integer (32 bits, in Big Endian format as used by MP4)

```
//# write integer (in_val) as 32 bits in BIG Endian format at a position within an Array (in_Array)
//# params: ( write target: in_Array, write position: in_Offset, Value to write: in_val )
function write_uint32_BE ( in_Array, in_Offset, in_val )
{
    in_Array[ in_Offset + 0 ] = (in_val & 0xFF000000) >>> 24;
    in_Array[ in_Offset + 1 ] = (in_val & 0x00FF0000) >>> 16;
    in_Array[ in_Offset + 2 ] = (in_val & 0x0000FF00) >>> 8;
    in_Array[ in_Offset + 3 ] = (in_val & 0x000000FF);

}
```

So to create different atoms (or boxes) of MP4 data you have to do the following...

- Check the specifications for the [minimum required atoms](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/QuickTime_container#General_File_Organization) (for a valid MP4 file).
- Write integers (32-bits) to represent the atom/box data (*eg:* its required data entries)

These example bytes are for an `stss` box (tells which frame nums are keyframes. 
 For more info on `stss` atom/box then see [**S**ample **T**able - **S**ync **S**amples](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicktime-file-format/sync_sample_atom)):

The example bytes of an STSS atom that hold two keyframes look like:

```
00 00 00 18 73 74 73 73 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 08
```

where each 4 bytes means:

`[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18]` = Size **0x18** in Hex means **24** in Decimal 
`[0x73, 0x74, 0x73, 0x73]` = is ASCII text of "**stss**" 
`[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]` = version etc 
`[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02]` = total number of entries of Keyframes 
`[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01]` = entry 1 = **0x01** == **frame 1** 
`[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08]` = entry 2 = **0x08** == **frame 8**

We can see that frame 1 and frame 8 are both keyframes. The MP4 decoder will not crash so far.

To create the above bytes by code you would run the "write 32-bit uint" function 6 times:

```
write_uint32_BE ( myMP4_bufferArray, (someOffsetposition + 0), 0x00000018 );
write_uint32_BE ( myMP4_bufferArray, (someOffsetposition + 4), 0x73747373 );
write_uint32_BE ( myMP4_bufferArray, (someOffsetposition + 8), 0x00000000 );
write_uint32_BE ( myMP4_bufferArray, (someOffsetposition + 12), 0x00000002 );
write_uint32_BE ( myMP4_bufferArray, (someOffsetposition + 16), 0x00000001 );
write_uint32_BE ( myMP4_bufferArray, (someOffsetposition + 20), 0x00000008 );
```

Creating the bytes of an MP4 is a [whole other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552833/2057709).

You need to first be able to encode a frame...

Try this code below for encoding a test video frame... 
It will encode only to H264 (compressed picture) format. You will need to write more code to create bytes of a container format like MP4 (or even AVI, FLV, MOV, MKV, etc). This is called muxing and you can try a library like Mux.js, MP4Box.js, or else write your own muxing code to put audio/video frames into one container.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="320" height="240" style="" >

</canvas>

<script>

var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

//## Encoder vars
var fileName;
var is_keyFrame = true;

var myConfigBytes;
var encoded_chunkData;

var frameFromCanvas;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//# Phase (1)
//# Setup an Encoder ...

const encoder_init = {
    output: handleChunk,
    error: (e) => { console.log("Encode error : " + e.message) },
};

const encoder_config = {
    
    //# set codec
    codec: "avc1.42C01E", //# works 420 Baseline profile
    
    //# set AVC format to "annexb" to get START CODES added automatically
    avc: { format: 'annexb' },
    
    //# best to set when decoding, not when encoding
    //hardwareAcceleration: 'prefer-hardware',
     
    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    
    framerate: 30,
    
    latencyMode: "realtime",
    //latencyMode: "quality", //# (default)
    
    //bitrateMode: "constant",
    bitrateMode: "variable",
    
    //# if you want to set it manually
    //bitrate: 500_000, //# test 500 kbps
    //bitrate: 2_000_000, //# test 2 Mbps
    
};

const encoder = new VideoEncoder( encoder_init );
encoder.configure( encoder_config );
console.log(">>> Encoder is now ready");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//# Phase (2)
//# Create Image data ...

var vid_width = 320; var vid_height = 240;

myCanvas.setAttribute( "width", vid_width );
myCanvas.setAttribute( "height", vid_height );

var ctx_frame = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
var ctx_frame_imageData = ctx_frame.createImageData( vid_width, vid_height );

//# //# fill canvas with some R-G-B values at each pixel component
for (let i = 0; i < ctx_frame_imageData.data.length; i += 4) 
{
    //# Modify pixel data (blue square on main canvas)
    ctx_frame_imageData.data[i + 0] = 200; //# R value
    ctx_frame_imageData.data[i + 1] = 190; //# G value
    ctx_frame_imageData.data[i + 2] = 90;  //# B value

    ctx_frame_imageData.data[i + 3] = 255;  // Alpha value

}

//# Draw image data to the canvas
ctx_frame.putImageData(ctx_frame_imageData, 0, 0);


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//# Phase (3)
//# Encode the Image data as a Video Frame ...

frameFromCanvas = new VideoFrame( myCanvas, { timestamp: 0 });
encode_frame( frameFromCanvas );

function encode_frame ( frame )
{
    if (encoder.encodeQueueSize > 2) 
    {
        //# drop this frame (since 2 is too many frames in 1 queue)
        frame.close();
    } 
    else 
    {
        is_keyFrame = true; 
        
        //# encode as "keyframe" (or false == a "delta" frame)
        encoder.encode(frame, { keyFrame: is_keyFrame } );
    }
}

let tmp_obj_metadata;

//# handle chunks (eg: could mux frames into fragmented MP4 container)
async function handleChunk( encoded_frame_data, metadata) 
{
    if (metadata.decoderConfig) 
    {
        //# save the decoder description (is SPS and PPS for AVC / MP4 )
        myConfigBytes = new Uint8Array(  metadata.decoderConfig.description );
    }

    //# get actual bytes of encoded data
    encoded_chunkData = new Uint8Array( encoded_frame_data.byteLength );
    encoded_frame_data.copyTo( encoded_chunkData );

    //# end the encoding session (eg: if no more frames are expected)
    let temp = await encoder.flush();
    
    //# test save of encoded bytes
    myFile_name = "vc_test_encode_webcodecs_05.h264"
    
    //saveArrayToFile( encoded_chunkData, myFile_name )
    
    return temp;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//# Phase (4)
//# Save H.264  as file...

function saveArrayToFile( in_Array, in_fileName ) 
{
    let temp_out_bytes = [...myConfigBytes, ...in_Array]
    
    let myBlob = new Blob(  
                            [ Uint8Array.from( temp_out_bytes ) ] , 
                            {type: "application/octet-stream"} 
                        );
                        
    let myBlob_url = window.URL.createObjectURL( myBlob );
    let tmpOutFile = document.createElement("a");

    tmpOutFile.href = myBlob_url;
    tmpOutFile.download = in_fileName;
    tmpOutFile.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL( myBlob_url );
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```