# VLC video streamed video is not working due to it saved as corrupted video

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, vlc, video-editing

I have recorded a video using VLC stream. At the end of the record, I clicked the stop button and closed the player within a few seconds. now the video is not playable I have used this feature before and it worked well.

Due to the player's quick close, I assume the video is not working now.
I check the codec details and it's missing. workable videos have H264 - MPEG-4 VAC.

is there any way to fix this? I have attached details of the playable video and the current video.[a video taken from the same way and the current video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6gN0.png)

OS - Windows 11

I have tried to convert the video to avi format using vlc but it doesn't start the converting.
I have tried to update the player but it is the latest version.

Comment: Look on [Google search for `MP4 repair`](https://www.google.com/search?q=MP4+repair+tool+windows). Most likely you will have to download a tool for your Windows OS. You want a tool that expects another MP4 recorded correctly and with same settings like same resolution etc (they copy the metadata settings from the  working MP4 into the broken one).

Comment: @isuru prasad This also happened to me a few weeks ago. I thought, until I discovered your question, that I was just too stupid to use the VLC player. Anyway, I discovered that there is no track in the file. Open the file with Notepad++ and search for "trak". If "trak" is missing, all lists of frame information are missing.

Comment: @Daniel i checked the file and there are some "track" keywords. did you find a method to repair that ? Thanks for your feedback

Comment: @VC.One i have tried a few softwares. but none of them worked for me. i could get the audio file but couldn't get the video. anyway thanks for your feedback

Comment: @isuruprasad Cannot reproduce the issue in VLC. If I stop & then quickly close VLC then the output file plays for a few seconds (not complete, but works). When you say _"I have recorded a video"_ what is the source? Is it from your camera, or is it from online video links? If yes about getting online video then do you save that with any custom settings (for resolution, FPS, etc) and do you set a custom audio settings (like saving audio part as MP3 for audio)?

Comment: @VC.One what i did was, I recorded a video using a laptop webcam ( Media -> stream-> capture device ->  stream). As I remember I recorded it for around 3 hours.  The selected profile is " MPEG4 720p TV/device" ( FYI :
vcodec=h264,vb=1500,width=1280,height=720,acodec=mp3,ab=192,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none) 

When i use the same way for short videos, it works. but for a long video, I think the player needs some time to do something at the end of the video, like finishing some data or something.

The video is so important to me. I can't lose it. hope you understand it

Comment: @isuruprasad About _"When I use the same way for short videos"_ so did you use one of the short videos as input of a "working example" to those repair softwares and they all still couldn't get the picture part? I will test your settings and see if a new  working MP4 header can be recreated. Do you know any programming languages? I ask because I can help you to display first frame but you will have to take care of remaining 10,000+ frames yourself (or hire someone) to do a full recovery of the 3hr video.

Comment: @VC.One yeah I used a working short video as a sample for repairing tools. I am good with Javascript, and Typescript. I have a basic understanding of Java.

highly appreciate your support. I will take care of the other parts. I just want to know a proper method to recover this.

Comment: @isuruprasad Sorry I thought I updated with a possible repair process. I am currently dealing with another MP4 repair and remembered your question (came to check your progress)... Don't know if your problem is now solved? But just in case, I'll throw in an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the following tool will display your first frame... 
(only works with a VLC recordings @ 720p)

[Tool: Preview of first frame from corrupted MP4](https://vcone.github.io/public/demos/mp4_repair_01/)

If yes, then your MP4 is structured as following (showing first 64 bytes):

```
00 00 00 18 66 74 79 70 69 73 6F 6D 00 00 00 00     ....ftypisom....
6D 70 34 31 61 76 63 31 00 00 00 00 6D 64 61 74     mp41avc1....mdat
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 B0 06 05 FF FF     ...........°..ÿÿ
AC DC 45 E9 BD E6 D9 48 B7 96 2C D8 20 D9 23 EE     ¬ÜEé½æÙH·–,Ø Ù#î
```

*where:*
The **left side** is your bytes (written as Hex characters).
The **right side** is the decoded UTF-8 text (where possible to decode).

The hex digits `6D 64 61 74` are the beginning of your file's MDAT (Media Data) section. The previous **-4** bytes are `00 00 00 00` because VLC does not yet know how large the recording is (until you finish, then it updates that placeholder **0** size into the real number).

The next line has `06` (which is the **SEI** data) and where the previous **-4** bytes are giving a size of (hex) `00 00 02 B0` (or in decimal digits: size of **688** bytes).

You can test: `console.log( "Size is... " + 0x000002B0 ); //gives 688`
Javascript console always prints out as decimal format, to input a hex value just prefix the hex with `0x` (and no spaces between the hex digits).

**SEI** itself is not a video frame just some extra data that is useful to the MP4 decoder. To reduce playback problems, just include it in your Output followed next by adding the first keyframe.

**Always use a hex editor to double-check when working with file bytes**

From research you will learn that an MP4 file is divided into two main sections. There is `moov` which holds the metadata (required for decoder setup and also for the byte positions of each frame, etc). The other section is `mdat` and this section holds the raw audio/video bytes.

A corrupted VLC recording (into MP4) only has the `mdat`section.

An MP4's `mdat` section has this chunk structure:

```
[ x4 bytes = chunk SIZE ] [ xN bytes = chunk DATA ]
```

##### Repair as MP4 (hardest)

To repair you can use an existing MP4 to know the required "atoms" and copy them over into a new (repaired) set of bytes. You need to edit a section called the **Sample Table** (find `stbl` in the file) and update those details (which frames are keyframes? Which byte positions? Which timestamps for frames? etc).

More info: [MP4 Atom parsing - How To Configure Time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552833/2057709)

##### Repair as H.264 (easiest)

The easiest fix is to try to extract the H.264 frames manually from the MP4 and then later use FFmpeg (or VLC) to combine these video frames with your previously extracted audio (from using the repair software).

To extract video frames, you need to cycle through the chunks (called NAL units) inside the MP4.

Your first NALU (of type **SEI**) is at a position (also called offset) of **44**. From that byte position you can **step backwards by four bytes**, and then from that new position you can now **get the length of NALU** by reading those 4 bytes (as one 32-bit unsigned integer, it is unsigned because we don't expect to see any minus symbol, only getting back a positive number).

I will throw in some utility functions to get you started:

To read a 4-byte value from a position in Array:

```
function read_UInt32_BE_in_Array( in_array, startPos )
{
    return ( (in_array[ startPos+0 ]) << 24 | (in_array[ startPos+1 ]) << 16 | (in_array[ startPos+2 ]) << 8 | (in_array[ startPos+3 ]) );
}
```

To write a 4-byte value into a position in Array:

```
function write_UInt32_BE_in_Array( in_val, in_array, startPos )
{
    in_array[ startPos+0 ] = ( (in_val >> 24) & 0x000000FF );
    in_array[ startPos+1 ] = ( (in_val >> 16) & 0x000000FF );
    in_array[ startPos+2 ] = ( (in_val >>  8) & 0x000000FF );
    in_array[ startPos+3 ] = ( (in_val >>  0) & 0x000000FF );
}
```

The process (in pseudo-code):

```
myCurrentPos = 44; //# start of SEI data
type_NALU = myBytes[ myCurrentPos ]; //# check NALU type, should be a 6 if SEI data
sizePos = (myCurrentPos - 4); //# go back -4 steps to reach "size" bytes
sizeNum = read_32bit_BigEndian_at_Pos( sizePos ); //# read the 4 size bytes (in Big Endian format)

//# copy bytes (Array slots) from offset "myCurrentPos" up to position of +"sizeNum".

//# skip to next frame
myCurrentPos += ( sizeNum + 4 );
type_NALU = myBytes[ myCurrentPos ]; //# check NALU type, is a 0x65 (dec: 101) if Keyframe data.

//# repeat process of re-reading "sizePos" and "sizeNum" and then copy by this length.
```

- Copy only NALU types of (hex format): **0x06**, **0x65**, **0x41**, **0x42** and **0x43** 
  (or same in decimal format: 6, 101, 65, 66, 67).
- If NALU **is not that type then skip it** by using its size to get to the next NALU.
- Use `array.slice()` to copy/extract Input byte values into a new Output array

In your Output array (per frame)...

- First **write** four bytes: `00 00 00 01` (creates an H264 start code for new data).
- Then **paste in** your copied "chunk" bytes.
- Repeat for another frame until end.

Finally save output file as `test.h264` and try to play in a media player.
Next use FFmpeg or VLC to combine the H264 video file with the extracted MP3 data.

Comment: Highly appreciate your support. I will try and let you know.

Comment: OK. Just re-read the Answer whenever you're stuck (also I updated it a little bit), or ask here in comments.